# Json java servlet

Tags: javascript, java, json, servlets

I'm building a servlet for a school assignment, the assignment is to build an access point for a airplane with a captive portal (servlet)

The structure is build but the connection with the database is a big question mark.

We have two pages:

1. the index page/landing page
2. the rerouting page

On page one there is a text field where the user has to fill in his or her ticketnumber.

Under here page 1.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


        out.println("<!doctype html>");
        out.println("<html lang=\"en-US\">");
        out.println("<head>");

            out.println("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">");

            out.println("<title>Login</title>");

            out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.css\">");
        out.println("</head>");

        out.println("<body background=\"images/bg.jpg\">");

            out.println("<section>");
                out.println("<div id=\"login\">");

                out.println("<img class=\"headerImage\" src=\"images/corendon.png\"/>");
                out.println("<img class=\"ticketIcon\" src=\"images/ticketIcon.png\"/>");

                    out.println("<h2></h2>");

                    out.println("<form name=\"myForm\" action=\"loginPage\" method=\"get\" onSubmit=\"event.preventDefault(); redirect(); return false;\">");

                        out.println("<fieldset>");

                            out.println("<p><label for=\"upper\"></label></p>");

                            out.println("<div>");
                                out.println("<p><input id=\"ticketnumber\" placeholder=\"ticketnumber..\" name=\"ticketnummer\"/></p>");
                            out.println("</div>");

                            out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cb1\" name=\"cb1\"/>");
                            out.println("<label for=\"cb1\" id=\"cb1text\">Ik accepteer de voorwaarden</label>");

                            out.println("<p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go Online\"></p>");

                            out.println("<p><span id=\"validation\"></span></p>");
                            out.println("</fieldset>");

                    out.println("</form>");
                out.println("</div>");
            out.println("</section>");

                out.println("<script type=text/javascript>");
                    out.println("function redirect(){");
                        out.println("var x = document.myForm.ticketnummer.value;");
                        out.println("var ticketnummer = \"1234\";");
                        out.println("if ((cb1.checked == 1)&&(x == ticketnummer)){");
                            out.println("window.location=\"loginPage?ticketnummer=\" + x");
                        out.println("}else {");
                            out.println("document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML=\"login onsuccesvol\";");
                            out.println("return false;");
                            out.println("}");

                    out.println("}");
                out.println("</script>");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

onder here page 2:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String ticketNumber = request.getParameter("ticketnummer");

    // ip address
    String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
        if (ipAddress == null)
        {  
            ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
        };


        out.println("<!doctype html>");
        out.println("<html lang=\"en-US\">");
        out.println("<head>");

            out.println("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">");

            out.println("<title>LoginAccepted</title>");

            out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/styleLoginPage.css\">");
        out.println("</head>");

        out.println("<body background=\"images/bg.jpg\">");

            out.println("<section>");
                out.println("<div id=\"login\">");


                out.println("<img class=\"headerImage\" src=\"images/corendon.png\"/>");


                    out.println("<h2></h2>");

                    out.println("<form>");

                        out.println("<fieldset>");

                            out.println("<p><label for=\"upper\"></label></p>");
                                out.println("<div id=\"welcome\">");

                                        out.println("U bent nu ingelogd in het netwerk!");
                                        out.println("Corendon wenst u een fijne vlucht en");
                                        out.println("veel internetplezier toe.");
                                        out.println("<img class=\"loginImage\" src=\"images/loginImage.png\"/>");

                                out.println("</div>");
                        out.println("</fieldset>");

                    out.println("</form>");
                out.println("</div> <!-- end login -->");
            out.println("</section>");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        if (ticketNumber.equals("1234")) {
            try {  
                 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime ();

                 Process process = rt.exec ("/var/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/unblock.sh " + ipAddress);

                 InputStreamReader reader = 
                 new InputStreamReader ( process.getInputStream () );  

                 BufferedReader buf_reader =  
                 new BufferedReader ( reader ); 

                 String line;  
                 while ((line = buf_reader.readLine ()) != null)  
                 System.out.println (line);  

                 }  
                    catch (IOException e) {  
                        System.out.println (e);
                 }
        }
```

my question: how do I add the json query in these scripts?

for example:

```
{
"function":"List",
"teamId": "IN[key]",
"teamKey":"[key]",
"requestId": "0"
}
```

the feedback will be:

```
{"requestId":"0", "result":"0", "passengers":[{"uni":"d565c05f-596b-46a2-b302-a055148b8fb1","surName":"Boogaard","firstName":"Chiel"},{"uni":"e431fc48-c2bf-4e84-a7c6-414e5b86dff9","surName":"","firstName":""},{"uni":"1c7e3cee-b445-45ab-9397-cdc7c80370c8","surName":"Wolf","firstName":"Jesse"},{"uni":"22ad0d5c-698e-4711-9b91-e21bf9d6e932","surName":"Hansali","firstName":"Amin"}]}
```

and the ticket number request:

```
{
"function":"List",
"teamId": "IN103-1",
"teamKey": "c2f590a4-abab-4e73-b65f-1aef785c6c75",
"requestId" : "0"
}
```

and feedback:

```
{"requestId":"0", "result":"0", "tickets":[{"uni":"e092058c-da83-4970-829a-a56a516fd6a3","usedInternet":"0","uniPassenger":"e431fc48-c2bf-4e84-a7c6-414e5b86dff9","uniFlight":"719d922c-e38d-4aac-afe2-4a36ba900865","ticketNumber":"1234567890"}]}
```

how do I check the filled in ticketnumber in the servlet with the database using json? 
by the way I cannot use PHP or ASP

Comment: so you want to receive parameters as json and write some output as json to the response instead of html?

Comment: yes i know its not the right way, but after the project i will never use the servlet or maintain it

Comment: i am trying to make:
if ((cb1.checked == 1)&&(x == ticketnummer)){

and the ticket number has to be checked at the database

Comment: @chiel.boogaard, but someone else will have to, somewhere, someday :`( legacy projects...

Comment: i know but its for this one project at school and thats it, it will be tested and will be showed to my teacher and then press delete :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did mess with your project.
Please follow:
1. Create jsp file in the web folder - there are your request and response params. Freely use html here.
If there are problems include jsp-api.jar into the project.

2. Use JQuery in your front end project. Download jquery from anywhere there are tons of copies on the internet - download only one of them.
   Include jquery.js file in above mentioned jsp.
3. Open a script tag and then write:

function queryData(your_query_object){

$.ajax({

```
   url: 'some_servlet',

   type: 'GET',

   data: your_query_object,

   success: function(response){

                          alert(response);

                      },

   error: function(reason){

                alert(reason);
              }
```

});

}

Then call that function with your query object:

```
  queryData(queryObject);
```

By calling this function you are sending http request to some servlet. And handle the request just as you do it in usual cases - parameter names are just as you put in your json query object. Your query object is

{
"function":"List",
"teamId": "IN103-1",
"teamKey": "c2f590a4-abab-4e73-b65f-1aef785c6c75",
"requestId" : "0"
}

So get these values in the servlet like this:

request.getParameter("function");

I am supposing  you know javascript, you know also http rules; and I hope you have learned how servlet-mapping is done. If NO you should go and read something about webapp with java and javascript.

Also consider no one makes your homework for you.

Comment: haha yes i know no one makes my homework :P but i cant figure this part out so it turned to the community to help me out. and thank you! this helped me alot already!

Comment: At the beginning I also asked any questions that I was stuck with. Then I got downvoting. So I try to not to ask question, which could have probability at least 30% of existance.

Comment: sorry i dont fully understand your comment

Comment: In your question you asked too much things which does not suite to Stackoverflow standards. Question must be oriented to a specific problem, and form of answer is not excepted as well. Your question is to broad...